# "Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist" while compiling a word template in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

when I try to compile a pre-existing model (dotx) , i have this error : 
"Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist"

The code used in vb is the following:

```
 Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(App.Path & "\Example.dotx")   
    wDoc.FormFields("tExampleHelloWord").Result = "HelloWord"
```

In Word 2007, I simply created a text control and set the tag with : tExampleHelloWord